Pylint and ruff don't complain about useless (unnecessary) return in functions with docstring
In pylint docs we read:

Emitted when a single "return" or "return None" statement is found at
the end of function or method definition. This statement can safely be
removed because Python will implicitly return None

In ruff docs on PLR1711 we read:

What it does
Checks for functions that end with an unnecessary return or return None, and contain no other return statements.

Sounds like in ruff's documentation unnecessary return or return None refers to such statement with removal of which the function would stay practically the same.
So both ruff and pylint should flag this return, right?:
def f():
    """docs"""
    return None

But they don't. I ran this in fresh google colab environment:
!pip install pylint ruff>/dev/null
!pylint --version && ruff --version
!printf "\nDOCS :\n"
!printf 'def f():\n    """docs"""\n    return None' > a.py
!pylint --disable C a.py
!ruff check --extend-select PLR1711 a.py
!printf "\nPRINT :\n"
!printf 'def f():\n    print()\n    return None' > a.py
!pylint --disable C a.py
!ruff check --extend-select PLR1711 a.py

and got:


pylint 3.3.1
astroid 3.3.5
Python 3.10.12 (main, Sep 11 2024, 15:47:36) [GCC 11.4.0]
ruff 0.7.4

DOCS :

------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10

All checks passed!

PRINT :
************* Module a
a.py:1:0: R1711: Useless return at end of function or method (useless-return)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 6.67/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, -3.33)

a.py:3:5: PLR1711 [*] Useless `return` statement at end of function
  |
1 | def f():
2 |     print()
3 |     return None
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ PLR1711
  |
  = help: Remove useless `return` statement

Found 1 error.
[*] 1 fixable with the `--fix` option.


So can we get these tools to complain about such returns?

Pylint triggers useless-return if I add some code in the function before the return, for example print("something"). So maybe there is a bug, maybe the rule is more subtle than its documentation says.

The exact logic that Ruff uses to check for PLR1711 "useless return statement" is spelled out in useless_return.rs, complete with detailed comments that explain each check.
In this case, it looks like Ruff (and possibly PyLint) has special exceptions for (a) functions that consist solely of a return statement, and (b) functions that consist solely of a docstring plus a return statement.
Case (a) is fairly obvious; a function needs a body, and pass is rather less explicit (and less intuitive) than return None. Case (b) is an extension of case (a): the presence (or absence) of a docstring should not normally affect how a function is interpreted, and a function that contains only a docstring will look rather unfinished, whereas a function that contains an explicit return None makes it clearer that this is intended behaviour.
Keep in mind that lint rules are typically intended to be pragmatic, rather than absolute. This is why exceptions to the rules exist. It may be the case that the documentation needs to be updated, which would be a perfectly reasonable thing to ask for.
If the lint logic bothers you, you are welcome to build your own checks (actually not hard, using the ast module), or fork an existing linter and modify the rules to taste.

Here's the original merge request in pylint:

produces a message only if there is a single return statement
in the function body. Otherwise _check_consistent_returns() is called!
Per its implementation and PEP8 we can have a "return None" at the end
of the function body if there are other return statements before that!

As you can see the "only a docstring" case was not thought about or discussed during implementation and I reading this comment I suppose the "inconsistent-return" checker is what is used instead in the docstring case (I did not parse both your example to be sure, so take this with a grain of salt).
Later on, pylint started using a "primer" (linting on popular project). This use case could be caught by the primer and discussed if the checker was implemented from zero today... but only if the code that is primed had such an example.
Once the checker is implemented you only see the modified behavior when working on it, so you can't catch old bugs.
I would say it's very probable that this specific case was never discussed in pylint.
There's also the original ruff MR where making this consistent with multiple existing messages is considered but not what happens for docstring with a single return statement.
So I would say it's possible this was not considered in ruff nor pylint and that it's a false negative bug that happens to exists in two implementations. Maybe because it's not a code construct that is found often. I can't find an issue complaining about this in pylint nor ruff and the check was implemented respectively 6 years ago and in ruff's infancy...
